# Fatal error: Call to a member function is_connected() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, fatal-error

I am getting this error when I try to run my script:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_connected() on a non-object
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\models\ReadData_model.php on
>   line 7

```
<?php
class ReadData_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_table($target) {
        if ($target != 'sender' && $target != 'receiver') { exit('Error: Illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.'); }
        $this->load->model('Connection_model');

        if ($this->connection_model->is_connected($target)) { // This is line #7
            return $this->connection_model->get_custom_db($target)->list_tables();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

is_connected():

```
public function is_connected($target) {
    if ($this->get_custom_db($target)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('connection');
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the connection_model try capitalizing the first letter since you loaded it with one `$this->load->model('Connection_model');`

So when you use it it should be:

```
$this->Connection_model->is_connected($target))
```

I know it sounds stupid, but I have had some funky things happen like this while using Codeigniter.

Comment: Just went back to one of my old CodeIgniter projects and tested and got the same error when I loaded a model with a cap and then tried to call it with a lowercase and worked otherwise. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$this->connection_model` is properly initialized.

Comment: It should be. I use  `$this->load->model('Connection_model');` on line #5 to initialize it.

Comment: The fatal error says you're trying to call a method of a variable that is not an object. Maybe the load failed.

Comment: You were right. It was because of the uppercase. Thanks anyway!